# Change eclipse gradle settings

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a project that needs to be converted to a gradle project in order to handle dependencies. The issue is that eclipse's gradle plug in changes the directory structure to its default "com/java/src" among other things when I right click my project, configure, convert to gradle.

I want to know how to change the settings so that eclipse doesn't change around the structure. The project is too complicated to be fixed to work with the changes gradle enforces by default.

Comment: In many cases its easier to config in build.gradle and use Eclipse plugin to generate Eclipse project with dependencies correctly linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the project properties in gradle build file. The just use this to create the  project and import it to Eclipse.

> $> gradle eclipse

```
eclipse {
jdt {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}

classpath {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs.addAll( project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.path)
            java.srcDirs 'gen'
        }
    }

    plusConfigurations += configurations.compile
    containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    downloadSources = true
    downloadJavadoc = false


        }
    }
}

project {
    natures.clear()
    natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
    natures 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature'
    buildCommands.clear();
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
    buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
}
}
```